# Как передать значение типа radio

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть код:

Выберите:

```
<input id="f4" type="radio" name="etaj3" value="1" /> Первое    
<input id="f4" type="radio" name="etaj3" value="2" /> Второе
```

Каким образом передать на другой файл значение `$_POST['etaj3']` ?

Для передачи значений из типа **text** использую такой код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link").click(function() {
    var f1 = document.getElementById('f1');
    $.ajax({
      url: "file.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      data: {
        f1: document.getElementById('f1').value,
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $("#contentST").html(response);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Для выбора отмеченного варианта, Вы можете воспользоваться псевдоселектором [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

```
var qqqq = $('input[name="etaj3"]:checked').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно что вы имеете ввиду конкретно , но для формирования строки пригодной для передачи по url проще всего использовать метод `.serialize` (*сразу соберет все данные с формы в нужном формате*)

Например:

```js
$('#IdForm').submit(function() {

  $.post(
    'https://.../postform.php',
    $("#IdForm").serialize(),

    function(msg) {
      $('#IdForm').hide('slow');
      $('#IdMessage').html(msg);
    }
  );


});
```

Если вы хотите отправлять строку на разные `url`, в одной функции ajax этого сделать не получиться, вам нужно сделать отдельную или передавать значение `url` из другой функции:

```js
function (URL){
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: URL,
         data: {
         
             ...
         },
         success: function (data) {
             $("#IdMessage").text(data);
         }
     });
};
```